# Adjustment of intervals for research purposes

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

We are currently struggling with picking the correct statistical method for our research and would like to ask for your advice. In the research, We would like to group participants by personal income into one of the 3 categories – bottom 50%, mid 40% and top 10%. However, when we calculated the cumulative percentage, the differences are too broad (Please see the attached picture.), mainly because of the intervals. All of our data comes from the ISSP questionnaire. Therefore our questions are:

1. Please, is there any other way to rank participants in order to get desired 50 – 40 - 10 distribution, besides using the other variables? If not, please what variables would you suggest to use?
2. As you can see, some respondents chose to not answer income related question. Please, do you think that we can impute income levels for people with missing data?
3. As you can see on the picture, over 13% of respondents stated that they have no paid income, the reasons for it can be discussed. Please, should we count people without income in the bottom 50%? If we do so, when we compare our results with the official data, they do not match.

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you very much for your time.

Have a nice day! :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKgAh.png)